# "QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded" when trying to create a database using QtSql in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, pyqt5, psql, qsqldatabase

I am trying to create a PostgreSQL database with PyQt5.
After creating a database using `QSqlDatabase.addDatabase()`, calling `lastError().text()` on that object returns the following:

```
Driver not loaded Driver not loaded
```

I have already tried

- copying libpq.dll from the PostgreSQL lib folder to Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin in my Python folder
- adding sqlite3 to Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin in my Python folder
- adding the PostgreSQL lib and include folders to the PATH

This is the code I am using to test:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
if not "QPSQL" in QSqlDatabase.drivers():
    print('QPSQL not in QSqlDatabase.drivers()')
qQslDb = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
qQslDb.setHostName('<Host>')
qQslDb.setDatabaseName('<Name>')
qQslDb.setUserName('<Username>')
ok = qQslDb.open()
if ok:
    print("OK, database is open")
else:
    print(qQslDb.lastError().text())
    exit()
```

---

**Edit**: `lastError().text()` actually only returns `Driver not loaded Driver not loaded`. These two lines

```
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL
```

come from the call to `QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")` if I am not mistaken.
For some reason though, when using bash to run the program these two lines are always at the very start of the command line output, even if I put a `print("test")` in the first line of the program. When using cmd however, it's in the "right" order.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver C++ syntax is different to Python syntax

Comment: Hmm, coffee has not kicked in. Does the code work with any of the other drivers, say 'QSQLITE'? What does ```QSqlDatabase.drivers()``` return?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ```QSqlDatabase.drivers()``` returns ```['QSQLITE', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']```. I tried following the [link=instructions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qpsql-plugin-on-windows) to build QPSQL, but I seem to be missing qmake (maybe because I installed qt using pip?). Same problem with the other listed drivers.

Comment: ```QSqlDatabase.drivers()``` is returning drivers so they are there and discoverable.  I don't see that you have to build them.  The issue seems to be that the drivers are seen but not loaded. Not sure yet why?

Comment: Is there a way you can the errors before ```lastError()```?

Comment: The [QSqlDatabase Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html) apparently doesn't have any other function to retrieve errors other than lastError() and that is pretty much being called as early as possible in my test program.
Also I forgot to add that in the folder Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\sqldrivers (within the Python folder) there are actually three files already, that have similar names to the listed drivers: qsqlite.dll, qsqlodbc.dll and qsqlpsql.dll.

Comment: Searching for other answers to this on SO found that it is often a dependency issue.  Where ```qsqlpsql.dll``` is not finding ```libpq.dll```.  The suggestion is to use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see if that is the case.

Comment: Dependency Walker says that the modules QT5SQL.DLL and QT5CORE.DLL are missing. LIBPQ.DLL has the module warning smbol beside it. There are a few dependencies of LIPBQ that are missing. Most of them are called something like "API-MS-WIN-CORE-...".